# What does "long a storytelling asset" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm not sure whether I'm right or not. I don't understand what "long a storytelling asset" means, but I assume that the whole first sentence says that the animation which used to make storytelling ease to grasp eventually became a liability. It means that the animation started to be used more for action scenes and less for storytelling itself. What do you think? Do I correctly understand this sentence?

> **Making matters even worse, the animation, long a storytelling asset, became a liability.** After all, Springfield is populated by cartoon
>   characters. Even the most gruesome injury or fatal fall can be shaken
>   off in the next scene, and the audience knows it. All the taut music
>   and sad dialogue in the world can’t make up for the fact that no one
>   is in any real danger.
>
> [source](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs8/)

Comment: "long a storytelling asset" = *[which had been] a valuable technique for storytellers for a long time.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case "long" is a common colloquial expression that means "for a long time".  Examples:

> Soybeans, and products made from them, have **long** been a staple of Asian cuisine.
>
> **Long** a popular hangout. the nightclub is expected to close by the end of this year.

In your example, the author is saying that the animation had been an asset *for a long time*, but is no longer.